# Can malware spread from Android to Windows

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, android, malware

Could malware from an Android-based smartphone affect a Windows Vista-based desktop PC via WiFi if both devices are connected to the same WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

If the Android malware had a scanner and payload specifically written to infect Windows machines, yes.

Any of the recent malware outbreaks could conceivably have been caused by an infected phone being connected to a company WiFi network. They weren't, mainly because there are enough machines already connected directly to the internet and companies generally only allow "secure" (locked down) mobile devices to connect to their networks, but the fact of the matter is that it is an attack vector.

An identical payload is unlikely to be able to function on both platforms due to the functional differences but there is nothing stopping malware on any one platform from carrying malware for other platforms in a Trojan horse style.

The only thing preventing it is the fact that every extra payload increases the chance of early detection.